# Insert not Returning Correct Values

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, sql-insert

So I have an UPDATE that I am trying to change into a INSERT

Here is the Original Update Statement (It takes to long on large volumes)

```
DECLARE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TOCTASK_ORIG TASKO
            SET c_ocactvty_childactiviti = 11200,
                i_ocactvty_childactiviti = 
                (SELECT PROI.I
                FROM TOCPROCESSINSTANCE PROI,
                    TOCSERVICEREQUEST SR
                WHERE TASKO.c_occontbs_tasks = 11011
                    AND TASKO.i_occontbs_tasks = SR.I
                    AND PROI.C_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.C
                    AND PROI.I_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.I
                )
            WHERE EXISTS
                      (SELECT 1
                        FROM TOCPROCESSINSTANCE PROI,
                            TOCSERVICEREQUEST SR
                        WHERE TASK.c_occontbs_tasks = 11011
                            AND TASK.i_occontbs_tasks = SR.I
                            AND PROI.C_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.C
                            AND PROI.I_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.I
                        );
        COMMIT; 
    END;
```

From researching online the best approach is to rewrite this as insert and make the changes along the way

Which I have done here is the SELECT clause for the INSERT

```
SELECT
TASKO.C
,TASKO.I
,11200  
,PROI.I
FROM TOCTASK_ORIG TASKO,
    TOCPROCESSINSTANCE PROI,
    TOCSERVICEREQUEST SR
WHERE TASKO.c_occontbs_tasks = 11011
    AND TASKO.i_occontbs_tasks = SR.I
    AND PROI.C_PROCESSIServiceRe = 11011
    AND PROI.I_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.I;
```

Problem is I currently have 110302 records in the original table, but when I run the insert into a new temp table it only creates 19,269 records. This number matches the second part of the WHERE Clause in which 19,269 should now match the PROI.I value the rest should be null

```
AND PROI.C_PROCESSIServiceRe = 11011
AND PROI.I_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.I
```

Problem is no other records are being created it just simply creates the 19,269 records and stops

Any help would be Great

Comment: for future: write INNER JOIN istead of comma. its ANSI-standard and will be easier to read for you and all others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure it out based of some of the above information provided

```
FROM TOCTASK_ORIG TASKO
LEFT OUTER JOIN TOCSERVICEREQUEST SR
ON TASKO.c_occontbs_tasks = SR.C
    AND TASKO.i_occontbs_tasks = SR.I
LEFT OUTER JOIN TOCPROCESSINSTANCE PROI
ON PROI.C_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.C
    AND PROI.I_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.I;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have observed, you are currently performing a `INNER JOIN` and thus only matching rows comes up. Whereas you actually need to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like

```
FROM TOCTASK_ORIG TASKO
LEFT JOIN     TOCSERVICEREQUEST SR ON TASKO.i_occontbs_tasks = SR.I
LEFT JOIN TOCPROCESSINSTANCE PROI ON PROI.I_PROCESSIServiceRe = SR.I
AND PROI.C_PROCESSIServiceRe = 11011
WHERE TASKO.c_occontbs_tasks = 11011;
```

Comment: Doing this only returned 19,316 rows, still not the 110302

Comment: You'd need to remove the where clause and use a case statement in the select list to determine which values to use - i.e. the original, or the changed value